# polyfills-es2015, vendor-es2015, main-es2015 and others are blocked due MIME type not allowed(text/html)?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, mime

Hi I have a problem when i make a deployment of my angular app, I mean when I serve it from angular it works fine but when i make a deployment on a tomcat server I get the errors and I cannot see anything related to components and modules, a little navbar i have in my `index.html` is loaded and thats all:

[image: When I make a deployment]

But when is serve from angular...

[image: it works fine!]

I made anothers deployment using Angular+PHP on Tomcat and never get these errors. Do you know why i am getting this?
Maybe it is something about `text/html`and `aplication/json` but not sure.

If you check the index.html in the `dist` folder you will find these:

[image: should I make some changes on the type? have tried <code>application/json</code>, <code>text/html</code> or what?]

Comment: Did you try `text/javascript` ?

Comment: yeah, ill post the image later but it give a similar error, 404, so it tries to get but cannot...

Comment: The problem is that NOT exist polyfills-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js... So, I supouse that, when server has not found return an html page error. you can build the app using `ng build --prod=true --outputHashing=none --namedChunks=false --vendorChunk=false` or (I'm not sure about this last), changing outputHashing=none in your angular.json

Comment: Yeah it exists but cannot recognize because of meta, I´ll try now your way.

Comment: Nothing has changed, i was reading about a wrong display`s scripts order but i dont think so. Gonna check this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13568

Comment: i did it!! @Eliseo

Comment: @OrestisZekai look to the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like that!!:
when you make a deployment sometime on your index.html generated by the `build` has a referente due to `"/"`
when it must be `"./"`, i dont know how it was generated by itself in that way but also you can solucionate by `<base href='http://localhost:port/distName/appName/'>`

Comment: Thank you so much :) After doing lot of things, this worked for me.

Comment: You are really wecolmen!!, happy to see that it is usefull

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

1. Check if the file exist in the dist folder
2. In the Developer tool, find the js files if it exists.
3. Check the angular.json, if the outputPath is right
4. Check the index.html if it has the `<base href="/">`
5. Also, check the setup of the .browserslistrc file.